# Chartist : empty space after stacked bars

Tags: javascript, charts, stacked

I use Chartist (spend lot of time to find a nice graphic lib).

Trying to get a stacked horizontal bar chart, I ended up fighting with a "bug".

In fact : I have 2 series to display (Data1, and Data2). The bars displayed on the pictures are made with the real numbers (2000 for Data1 on the left, and 1753.25 for Data2 on the right).

The number front of "Total" is a dummy data not used, don't care about it.

The problem is : the div into which the bars (SVG) is integrated is 100% of the parent, and the graph doesn't take all space (there's a space unused after it).

The options for chartist

```
var options = {
    axisX: {
      offset: 0,
      showLabel: false,
      showGrid: false
    },
    axisY: {
      offset: 0,
      showLabel: false,
      showGrid: false,
      scaleMinSpace: 10
    },
    width: '100%',
    height: "20px",
    chartPadding: {
      top: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0
    },
    stackBars: true,
    horizontalBars: true
};
```

So, I don't understand why there's this space.

Anybody here who can help ?
[Chart bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1h4o.png)

Answer (score 1):

In fact its the option "scaleMinSpace" on the axisX that has to be set to 1 (1 pixel). This way, the bar takes all the space available, no matter the quantity displayed.